# GWT Development mode - recommended browser (and version) for Linux

Tags: gwt, plugins, browser

i'm using Ubuntu 10.04 for GWT development and I noticed that on dev mode, the code runs faster on Firefox (in comparison to Chrome), but I'm thinking that even for Firefox there must be a version that runs faster, better for GWT Development mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DevMode runs half in Java (outside the browser) and half in JavaScript (within the browser), with a bit of native code (the DevMode plugin) in between.

The reason Chrome is slower than Firefox is that the DevMode plugin runs in a sandbox, so calls and data have to cross the sandbox boundaries.

Now, whereas latest versions of browsers always perform better than previous ones, it shouldn't change much things wrt DevMode performance. What costs the most is crossing the Java/JavaScript boundaries, which requires chatting over the network (even if it's generally localhost).

For best performances, try the [SuperDevMode](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/superdevmode), where everything runs in JavaScript in the browser: no plugin, no Java/JavaScript bridge over the netweork, just plain old JavaScript.

Comment: I have also tested my project (which is pretty big, 140k lines of code, client+server - GWT+GAE) on a Mac (8Gb ram) and although it runs  OK, i get an exception from JVM regarding memory heap - the dev mode is run with -Xmx2048m. Any idea why is that ?

Comment: Also, what does "DevMode plugin runs in a sandbox" means... for Chrome that is... ?

Comment: @ice13ill i think everything were well explained by Thomas. I believe the reason the plugin runs in sandbox, is related to chrome general plugins policy. You can have a good overview here : http://www.breakingpointsystems.com/resources/blog/chrome-sandbox/?printerFriendly